# how to add a sub domain .htaccess pointing to a folder outside the root

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I want to have a sub domain that points to a folder outside the normal public root folder.

```
httpdocs/
sub_dom/
```

So say "admin.domain.com" points to "sub_dom" while "domain.com" points to the regular httpdocs folder.

1. is this possible
2. is there a better solution (for example would it be better/more advisable to do it another way)

Currently the htaccess file contains this but it does not seem to do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub_dom/admin/ [redirect,last]
```

There is most probably something very wrong with the second line maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this possible

It is in vhost or server config. It is not possible using an htaccess file unless you can already access the `/sub_dom/` directory via your regular domain. You can't access any directory *outside of your document root* using your htaccess file.

> is there a better solution (for example would it be better/more advisable to do it another way)

The correct way to do it is to create a new vhost. Your old vhost should have server names something like this:

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

In your new vhost, you have:

```
ServerName admin.domain.com
```

And a:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/sub_dom/
```

The [Apache documentation has a tutorial for setting up vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Alternatively, you can create an alias from your regular domain, something like:

```
Alias /sub_dom /path/to/sub_dom
```

Then you can use mod_rewrite in your domain.com document root (httpdocs):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub_dom%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub_dom%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub_dom%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule ^ /sub_dom%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

But, you may as well just move `/sub_dom/` into `httpdocs`, it'll achieve the same thing.

Comment: This exactly what I am looking. I know that `vhosts` is the solution to point subdomain to outside root. I just realized that it can be done also with `alias`.

Comment: I am on a shared hosting plan and am not sure where to set up either of these alternatives in cpanel - or even if I can. Secondly, you wrote that moving /sub_dom/ into httpdocs will achieve the same thing - but won't that make those folders/files accessible from two URLs then? admin.domain.com and domain.com/admin ?