# Redirect wildcard subdomains to subdirectory, without changing URL in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I've read a lot of questions and answers about this on here but none that seem to solve my specific problem.

I want to redirect any subdomain to the subdirectory to match.

So: x.domain.com would go to domain.com/x, and y.domain.com would go to domain.com/y - But I want to do this without the URL in the address bar changing.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks 

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]

    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [P,L]
```

But this takes me to a website redirect loop, with an incorrect address in the URL bar where the subdomain still exists.

For example, x.domain.com takes me to x.domain.com/x and I get a redirect loop error.

I'd be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction! Nothing I change seems to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the vhost in the apache configuration is properly configured and all subdomains of domain.com are in the same host configuration (wildcard):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
...
```

You can get the redirect working with the following htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now, if you open asd.domain.com it should redirect you to domain.com/asd.
You will still have the problem, that the redirect is visible in the URL address bar. In order to prevent this, enable mod_proxy (and load the submodules) on your server and exchange the "L" flag with the "P" flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [P,NC,QSA]
```

If this doesn't work, viewing the vhost configuration and the content of error.log on subdomain calling will be helpful!

References:
[.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory) 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting some errors...
[Sun May 26 13:02:28 2013] [error] [client 2.126.187.186] Attempt to serve directory: proxy:http://domain.com/x/
[Sun May 26 13:02:29 2013] [error] [client 2.126.187.186] File does not exist: proxy:http://domain.com/x/favicon.ico

Comment: And when I visit the URL x.domain.com I get a 404, which says: The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: did it work before, when you had the flag "L" instead of "P"? I usually get the message "Attempt to serve directory: proxy:domain.com/x", when mod_proxy is not enabled! And just to be sure, you replaced "domain.com" with your real domain?

Comment: Aha! Mod_proxy wasn't enabled, that was it! I googled myself some answers on how to enable it and now it seems to be working! Thanks! I'll tick this.

Comment: Ahhhh, hang on!
Now I'm getting a redirect loop on www.domain.com, where it's trying to go to www.domain.com/www/www/www/www etc!

Comment: OK, I needed to put this line back in: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC] - Scared me for a second there!

Comment: Worked for me: 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [P,NC,QSA]`

Comment: This works for me using the L flag, but when using the P flag, I am unable to go to the directory itself but must append the index file to it.

For example, when using the L flag I can go to:
http://sub.domain.com and it will redirect me to domain.com/sub (and display index.php)
But using P:
http://sub.domain.com doesn't work but http://sub.domain.com/index.php does work

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't need to use `mod_proxy`. See my solution.

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved in `.htaccess` without `mod_proxy` provided your server is configured to allow wildcard subdomains. (I achieved that in JustHost by creating a subomain manually named `*`). Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Can you please help me out? I would like to redirect john.website.com to app.website.com/sort.php while keeping john.website.com in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

I named the subdirectories under `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` **match with** my subdomains like so:

```
/
 var/
     www/
         html/
              .htaccess
              subdomain1.domain.com/
              subdomain2.domain.com/
              subdomain3.domain.com/
```

Where `/var/www/html` stand as `'DOCUMENT_ROOT'`. Then put following code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%{HTTP_HOST}/
RewriteRule (.*) /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

It works as redirect **wildcard** subdomains to subdirectories, without changing URL in address bar.

Beside of [*vhost*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739765/4058484), you may also put the subdirectories outside root and access it using *alias* as described *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203027/4058484)*. Then put the same `.htaccess` code in that location.