# HOW TO: Set up a Virtual Host on Apache 2.4.4 [ MAC / *NIX ]

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

I am posting this because I recently had a lot of trouble setting up a Virtual Host with a MAMP stack, due to Apple's throttling of the useable PHP version on Mac OS 10.8's default Apache2 installation.

This is a very quick guide on what to do and I owe the solution to this question on Stack Overflow:

- [Information Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

You can think of this as a compilation of what worked for me, as the accepted answers had no effect, but rather those with a significantly lower score.

Similarly, every guide I have seen fails to mention some points which users answered with on the sourced question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### **Step 1:** Install and configure Apache.

Make sure you specify what port you want to listen on, for me I specified `8080`. This will be the case for this series of instructions.

`Listen 8080` - Default is 80

### **Step 2:** Edit your `/etc/hosts` file to spoof your loopback address, 127.0.0.1

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   some.example         # domain-name.domain-TLD
127.0.0.1   www.some.example     # The same as the above line, but with www. prefixed
```

*You should really add a handle for subdomains on your web server, Apache or Nginx (or whatever else you use. Something that routes www to non-www.*

### **Step 3:** Enable the Virtual Hosts import on Apache.

1. Open your `httpd.conf` file located within Apache2's subdirectories. *Usually within `/conf`*
2. Uncomment the line that resembles this: `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
3. Also uncomment this module import: `LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so`

### **Step 4:** Configure your Virtual Hosts file

4. Find your Virtual Hosts config, `httpd-vhosts.conf`, you can comment out the two example Virtual Hosts in the file. *Usually within `/conf/extra`*
5. Copy your own Virtual Host into the file from this template:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>                           # Change the 80 to the number Apache2 "Listen"s on. In my case, 8080
>     ServerName SERVER-ADDRESS                # E.g. mywebsite.local
>     ServerAlias WWW.SERVER-ADDRESS           # E.g. www.mywebsite.local
>     DocumentRoot " SERVER-FILE-ROOT "        # E.g. "Users/user-name/Sites"
>         <Directory />                        # This should be a full path, though
>             Require all granted              # Required for permission errors
>             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
>             AllowOverride none
>         </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

### You're Done!

Once your Virtual Host has been edited to your liking you are done, **just restart Apache and enjoy.**

This guide already includes the fixes implemented, but in-case you still get permission errors:

- You MUST make sure that your `DocumentRoot` is not inside any documents your user explicitly owns. If it needs to be, give `"Read Only"` access to "Everyone" on Mac for that particular folder, E.g. "Documents" or "Movies" etc....

Comment: (+plus) 
if you add this line on htttpd.conf 

`Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf`

open file 
`/private/etc/apache2/users/you_username.conf` 

`
<Directory /Users/you_username/Sites>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
`

Comment: I'm using `Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon)`, the default `httpd.conf` doesn't include line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as well as `/conf/extra`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer is much explanatory, the following 2 things are most important when you are migrating virtual hosts to apache 2.4

1. Go to `wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.x/conf/httpd.conf` find `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and uncomment to `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. Add the virtual hosts in `wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.x/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
        DocumentRoot "H:/Wamp/www/mysite"
        ServerName mysite
        ServerAlias mysite
        <Directory />
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Note: `<Directory **/**>` the / is important