# wordpress site copy to local machine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

I am using linux.

i have a server for my wordpress site The name of the site example.com {name is not real but for example).

i copied the entire directory  example.com from the server to my computer. the folder example.com has wp-config.php, wp-admin folder etc. Basically all the files of the site.

i also exported and imported mysql databe to my local mysql server.

Now how to configure my apache conf file and hosts file so that when i type example.com it should open my local website.

Presenlty i stored example.com in /user/home/public_html/example.com

Comment: are you using anything like MAMP/WAMP/LAMP?

Comment: yes LAMP and als have mysql

Comment: First copy the file while installing wordpress wp-config.php appears in screen copy that and paste it into your wordpress folder.
Important note : Use LAMPP server and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your wp config has been modified to match your local server settings, all you need to do explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739765/1580743).  Don't forget to restart your apache service!

Answer (score -1):

1. Open wp-config.php and set its credentials according to your
   local server.
2. Then import database to phpmyadmin.
3. Then use
   http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
   to find and replace all your urls.