# How to resolve a subdomain to subdirectory using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well I'm working on a software that uses mod_rewrite to route everything to the index.php page, but it becomes problematic with subdomains such as subdomain.example.com. In theory, it should resolve to example.com/subdomain, but it does not work this way.

So I wonder, can anyone please let me know if theres a way to route subdomain.example.com to example.com/subdomain using .htaccess? Thanks.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758204/redirect-wildcard-subdomains-to-subdirectory-without-changing-url-in-address-ba

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example\.com(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```