# How to mod_rewrite an url based on sudomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to achive is the following apache mod_rewrite:

Url -> Map to file:

```
*.example.com/**/* -> index.php/$1/$2
```

For example:

```
portal.example.com/ -> index.php/portal
portal.example.com/agb -> index.php/portal/agb
admin.example.com -> index.php/admin
admin.example.com/my/cool/subfolder -> index.php/admin/my/cool/subfolder
```

How can I reach this? Maybe something with RewriteCond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that all subdomains are pointing to the same host (wildcard). This is usually done in the configuration file of the Apache host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
...
```

Then you should get the desired redirect to work with the following configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Reference:
[Redirect wildcard subdomains to subdirectory, without changing URL in address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758204/redirect-wildcard-subdomains-to-subdirectory-without-changing-url-in-address-ba/16758666#16758666)

**Update 1:**

Here is the update for you multi-wild-card scenario. Note that I changed the last line - I explicitly call the index.php of the base url, like this the output of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] should be /index.php/portal/index.html (or php according to your Apache configuration).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://%2.%3/index.php/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thats almost exactly what I am looking for, but one thing is missing: portal.example.com/ isn't mapped to index.php/portal

Comment: I just tested this on my dev-server, and it worked. Is it possible, that you tested some redirects with R=301 before, so your browser cached some "old" redirect rules? What happens, if you clear the cache or try the same with another browser (with wich you didn't test before)?

Comment: Yes, I tested it now in IE and got the same result: If I try to access  portal.example.com/ (with and without /), I get $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = /index.php
If i access portal.example.com/agb I get $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = /index.php/portal/agb

Comment: And thats my complete code:
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: I updated my answer (and tested it) for your multi-wildcard scenario.

Comment: Thank you for yor help, but that not working. But I will solve it in another way. Thank you!